# how to give value to ComboBox

Tags: php, html, combobox, html-select

I Have a syntax

```
< form  method='post'>
< select name='url'>
< option value="depan.php">  Ruang Depan Lantai 1        </option>
< option>  Ruang Receptionist Lantai 1 </option>
< option>  Ruang Workshop Lantai 1     </option>
< option>  Ruang Tamu Lantai 1         </option>
< option>  Kamar Mandi Lantai 1        </option>
< option>  Ruang CS Lantai 2           </option>
< option>  Ruang Manager Lantai 2      </option>
< option>  Kamar Mandi Lantai 2        </option>
< option>  Dapur Lantai 3              </option>
< /select><br />
< input type="submit" value="Go" name='go'/></form>
```

on the data 'Ruang Depan Lantai 1' 
, I had to make depan.php and call the page to display the data.
how when in click 'go' data instantly appear without having to call the other data?
please help

Answer (score 2):

Change code to this

```
< form action="depan.php" method='post'>
< select name='url'>
< option value="Ruang Depan Lantai 1">  Ruang Depan Lantai 1        </option>
< option>  Ruang Receptionist Lantai 1 </option>
< option>  Ruang Workshop Lantai 1     </option>
< option>  Ruang Tamu Lantai 1         </option>
< option>  Kamar Mandi Lantai 1        </option>
< option>  Ruang CS Lantai 2           </option>
< option>  Ruang Manager Lantai 2      </option>
< option>  Kamar Mandi Lantai 2        </option>
< option>  Dapur Lantai 3              </option>
< /select><br />
< input type="submit" value="Go" name='go'/></form>
```

And in depan.php

$redirect=$_POST['url'];

```
use $redirect to redirect specific match. Using if condition.
```

Comment: on each option, there is a query to the database to display different data for each Ruang

Comment: Yes. You can achieve that in each `if` condition as u want.